# Pass response from REST API to AzureMap Control SDK

Tags: azure-maps

How do I pass the result from `https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile/pbf` to the Azure Map Control WebSDK? I would like to call the Azure Map endpoint from my API , so I don't need to maintain the key in JavaScript, and then pass the byte array to the web SDK for rendering. I was hoping for an easy method on the constructor, but I don't see one:

```
map = new atlas.Map('myMap',  {byte array result from api here});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The GetMapTile method has the image data for a map tile. Where as the Azure Maps Web SDK is an interactive map control which directly accesses the Azure Maps tiles. There is no need to grab the tiles server side and pass them down to the web SDK.

Comment: Azure Maps offers Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) integration for the authentication of requests for Azure Maps services. Source: related GitHub issue on Azure Maps samples repo were customer was worried about subscription key https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/issues/1 for more info see the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/azure-maps-authentication#authentication-with-azure-active-directory-preview

Comment: Adrian do you still have questions about this?

Comment: I'm working through the web sdk implementation using Azure AD. I'll post here if I have any other questions. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Alberto, this page throws a forbidden when I attempt to access the documentation for setting up Azure Maps with Azure AD. https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-authentication

Comment: it seems like it has been fixed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-authentication

Comment: That page helps, but I still can't find any documentation on how to set up the web sdk map constructor to take AAD rather than the subscription key

Answer (score 0):

If using Azure Active Directory (AAD) for authentication. source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-map-control

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
        center: [-122.33, 47.6],
        zoom: 12,
        language: 'en-US',
        authOptions: {
            authType: 'aad',
            clientId: '<Your AAD Client Id>',
            aadAppId: '<Your AAD App Id>',
            aadTenant: 'msft.ccsctp.net'
        }
    });
</script>
```